# PHP, DATATABLES: How Can I echo data FROM my Oracle TABLE into my DataTable Table, without receving error from JSON?

Tags: php, datatables

The code I am using cannot let me help to render properly the last string `($f)` because there are double quotes in the original oracle table. So I receive:

```
Error: Parse error on line 702:
...ueue_mail_respool", "verifica del numero
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

I tried to use `addslashes`, `htmlspecialchars` methods but I cannot show the content of rows `TEMPLATE_DESCRIZIONE`. I am trying with `str_replace` but it looks like it delete the double quotes, but the error remains!
 Please help me, thank you guys! ;)

```
echo "{ \"aaData\": [\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    $i++;
    $a = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $row["ID_CONFIG"]));
    $b = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $row["NOME_APPARATO"]));
  $c = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $row["SORGENTE"]));
    $d = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $row["VALIDA_DAL"]));
    $e = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $row["TEMPLATE_NAME"]));
  $f = str_replace("\"","",$row["TEMPLATE_DESCRIZIONE"]);

    if ($i < $NUM){
        echo "[ \"".$a."\", \"".$b."\", \"".$c."\", \"".$d."\", \"".$e."\", \"".$f."\"], \n";
    }else {
        echo "[ \"".$a."\", \"".$b."\", \"".$c."\",\"".$d."\", \"".$e."\", \"".$f."\"]\n";
    }
}
echo "] }";
?>
```

Comment: Maybe try using a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: could you please explain me the use of heredoc? thank you :)

Comment: That's what the link is for.

Comment: OkI am reading right now but I don't know how to use so if you can use heredoc with my '$f' variable will be useful :)

Comment: I tried this:
$f = <<< EOT
   $row["TEMPLATE_DESCRIZIONE"]
EOT;

but it sends me the following error:

<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '&quot;', expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\asset_monitoraggioServer.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />

Comment: Actually It looks like I solved the previous error using {variable} INSIDE EOT. The probem is that the main error still happens. I don't know what I can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to produce string in JSON format.

For example:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)){
   array_push($data, array(
      $row["ID_CONFIG"],
      $row["NOME_APPARATO"],
      $row["SORGENTE"],
      $row["VALIDA_DAL"],
      $row["TEMPLATE_NAME"],
      $row["TEMPLATE_DESCRIZIONE"]
   ));
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
print json_encode(array("aaData" => $data));
```